# Tell flash sandbox to only allow local

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, sandbox

Is there a way to allow a Flash app to access local files?

I've build an app that's just for local use and not for web use but i run into sandbox errors because the app consists of several .xml and .swf files.

I understand this can be changed by telling the security settings to trust the app but it should be easy to use so this is not an option.

I also know this can be achieved by porting the app to AIR but i really hope there's a simpler solution.

The app (swf) is embedded in a (local) html page.

Comment: Turns out that compiling with the argument "-use-network=false" will do the trick.... But i'd still like to know if it's possible to set the sandbox with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is precisely what AIR is for, and it shouldn't require any porting. Just change the player to Adobe Air in the flash tab under Publish Settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use AIR.

You can export swf file to flash projector ( .exe ( win ) .app ( mac os ) ).

how to:

1. goto: http://goo.gl/5iqnJ
2. download Projector or Projector content debugger. install it.
3. open your swf with it
4. Choose File -> Create Projector.( win ) on mac os something similar.

regards.